# How to generate a hardware PWM wave for driving an LED through RPIO?

Tags: gpio, led, pwm, pigpio, rpio

I've looked through the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/pwm_py.html) of RPIO, and used GPIO18 to get my PWM up and running.

This is my code:

```
from RPIO import PWM
servo = PWM.Servo()
servo.set_servo(18, 4000)
```

As explained in the example in the documentation, this is supposed to set a 4000us (4ms) pulse every 20ms.

However, when I run the code - the LED blinks only once - indicating that there was only one instance of the pulse. Even when I check it with an oscilloscope - I am able to fleetingly catch a singular pulse.

Isn't the code supposed to generate an indefinite PWM wave, like one froma function generator?

How do I go about getting a sustained PWM wave as opposed to just a single pulse? I only wish to use RPIO since it is DMA based.

Comment: "This module is currently in beta, please send feedback to chris@linuxuser.at"

Comment: *"Isn't the code supposed to generate an indefinite PWM wave, like one froma function generator?"* -> I would guess that the library cleans up after itself, i.e., resets the pin to a default state on exit.  So if you run exactly what you have here, not much will happen.  Try it with a passive loop at the end -- `while true sleep 1000` where the unit for sleep is milliseconds (I'm not a python user but I think that's what `os.sleep()` uses there).

Comment: [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) also uses DMA to time pulses (as does servoblaster).

Comment: @goldilocks alternatively, I think enclosing the aforementioned code in a 'for' loop for a sufficient range should also work?

Comment: @joan are there functions in pigpio that I can use to get rid of the for loop complication? Is there a provision for me to get a sustained pwm pulse?

Comment: A `for` loop would repeat that code over and over.  That's certainly not what you want.  You are correct in believing this should set the state of the pin, and it will remain in that state *until changed*.  The catch is, when the python script exits, the GPIO library probably resets the state of the pins to their default state.  This is desirable because the "default state" tends to be the safest one (generally, input).

Comment: @user8244 Yes, but I wouldn't call it a complication with RPIO, you just need the RPIO script to be running when you want the pulse.  pigpio provides plenty of ways to generate DMA timed pulses.  Try `sudo pigpiod` (to start the daemon) and `pigs s 18 2000` to start servo pulses.  Also see the pigs hp command.

Comment: Note that the active control joan is talking about may not apply to the lib you are using; a handful of pins (12, 13, 18, 19) have hardware clocks (but there are only two, controlling two pins each), and it is possible to set the state of the clock/pin, then the software does not do any timing (so the issue would just be delaying the library reset).

Comment: @goldilocks I tried putting it in a for loop - it worked okay for 10 and 100 iterations - but it froze for 500 and 1000 (to the point that I had to pull the power to stop the program). This does indeed seem like a shabby way to go about it.  What do you think I can do within RPIO to get a sustained PWM wave?

If not - I might have to move to pigpio

Comment: As I said already: *"A `for` loop would repeat that code over and over. That's **certainly not** what you want."* What you want is to delay the program exit.  If you make it an infinite loop (`while true`) you can simply stop it via Ctrl-C.

Comment: @goldilocks I tried the code you mentioned earlier - it resulted in my monitor going to sleep.

Comment: If you mean it didn't cause the LED to work and after five minutes of waiting your monitor went to sleep, okay -- I dunno what's up.  But if you mean your monitor went to sleep immediately, it is either coincidence or your system is possessed by the supernatural.

Comment: Here's a suggestion though: Find *a complete example* of using PWM in python for the Pi and try it.  Pretty sure joan's site (for pigpio) should have one, at the very least.  If that doesn't work, edit it into your question and include a photograph or schematic illustrating your wiring. BTW: *"I only wish to use RPIO since it is DMA based"* not sure what your reasoning is there, but if it is because  "it uses minimal CPU resources", that's only in relation to bit-banging (the worst method).  A lib which just works with the hardware clocks uses *no CPU resources*.

Comment: I had used the line 'sleep' instead of 'time.sleep'. The first resulted in the monitor going to sleep. But time.sleep worked! Thanks!